# Artifact and X.Org problem in Xubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, amd-graphics

When Ubuntu logs in automatically, I get this weird artifact issue on the main screen. It has an AMD A9 APU.

The image shows that the top bar is okay but the rest of the screen is not.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug as described in [Xubuntu 20.04 AMD-users: Garbled display fix : xubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/gb9jiu/xubuntu_2004_amdusers_garbled_display_fix/). You need to run below command in either a terminal or TTY

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "glx" --create
```

Restart the computer after running the command.

Comment: Also worked with HD 7870.

Comment: I accidentally ran this command in . How can I return to the previous set-up?